# assembly language using visual studio C++ how to declare float?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, fpu

i have here my codes and i dont know how to declare, input and output a float type number. in c, %f is for float. i tried it in my codes and its not working. i also tried REAL 8. here's my code. i know that %d is for integer but when i use %f the output is 0.000000 i cant output the exact answer.

```
.386
.model flat, c
.stack 100h


printf      PROTO arg1:Ptr byte, printlist:VARARG
scanf       PROTO arg2:Ptr byte, inputlist:VARARG

.data
in1fmt      byte "%d" , 0
msg1fmt     byte 0Ah, "%s" , 0
msg2fmt     byte 0Ah, 0Ah, "%s" , 0
msg3fmt     byte 0Ah,"%s%d" , 0Ah, 0Ah, 0
msg4fmt     byte 0Ah,"%s%d" , 0Ah, 0Ah, 0Ah, 0Ah, 0
msg5fmt     byte 0Ah, "%s%d" , 0Ah, 0Ah,  0
msg1        byte "Enter any number: " , 0
msg2        byte "Enter another number: " , 0
msg3        byte "The sum is: " , 0
msg4        byte "The product is: " , 0
msg5        byte "The largest is: ", 0

num1        sdword ?
num2        sdword ?
sum         sdword ?
product     sdword ?
largest     sdword ?

.code
main        proc
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1
INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR num1
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg2fmt, ADDR msg2
INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR num2

mov eax, 0
mov eax, num1
add eax, num2
mov sum, eax
mov eax, 0
mov eax, num1
imul num2
mov product, eax
mov eax, 0
add eax, num1
.if eax > num2
mov eax, num1
mov largest, eax
.else
mov eax, 0
add eax, num2
mov largest, eax
.endif

INVOKE printf, ADDR msg3fmt, ADDR msg3, sum
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg4fmt, ADDR msg4, product
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg5fmt, ADDR msg5, largest

ret
main        endp
end
```

Comment: You are using `imul`, so the result is not a float but an int (hence the `i`in `imul`. If you want to calculate with floats, you should use the floating point instructions.

Comment: As for which type to use; there's `REAL4` (`dd` might also work).

Comment: i also tried the floating point instructions and it didnt work. :(

Comment: @Michael i see. REAL8 is double and REAL4 is float. i change the sdword to REAL4 and nothing happens.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown us the actual code you're using (the one you've included in your question reads/processes/prints integers), so it's not really possible for anyone except you to find the problem.

Comment: you need to transfer floating point variables from the data section into the floating point stack before using any floating point math operations.

Comment: RTFM! Here's a good tutorial on FPU: http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/

Comment: i tried it already. changing the sdword to real4 and nothing happened. this program is like changing C to assembly using visual studio C++.

Comment: @Michael that is my actual code. im using visual studio C++ and that's how we program assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The only real stumbling block is that 'printf' expects a double (REAL8) on the stack even for `"%f"`.

```
.686
.model flat, c

INCLUDELIB MSVCRT.LIB

; If MSVCRT.LIB doesn't exist try the first or both of the following libs
; includelib libcmt.lib
; includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

printf     PROTO arg1:Ptr byte, printlist:VARARG
scanf      PROTO arg2:Ptr byte, inputlist:VARARG

.data
    in1fmt      byte "%f" , 0
    msg1fmt     byte 0Ah, "%s" , 0
    msg2fmt     byte 0Ah, 0Ah, "%s" , 0
    msg3fmt     byte 0Ah,"%s%f" , 0Ah, 0Ah, 0
    msg4fmt     byte 0Ah,"%s%f" , 0Ah, 0Ah, 0Ah, 0Ah, 0
    msg5fmt     byte 0Ah, "%s%f" , 0Ah, 0Ah,  0
    msg1        byte "Enter any number: " , 0
    msg2        byte "Enter another number: " , 0
    msg3        byte "The sum is: " , 0
    msg4        byte "The product is: " , 0
    msg5        byte "The largest is: ", 0

    num1        REAL4 ?
    num2        REAL4 ?
    sum         REAL8 ?         ; printf needs a double as argument
    product     REAL8 ?         ; printf needs a double as argument
    largest     REAL8 ?         ; printf needs a double as argument

.code
main proc
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1
    INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR num1
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg2fmt, ADDR msg2
    INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR num2

    fld num1
    fadd num2
    fstp sum

    fld num1
    fmul num2
    fstp product

    fld num1
    fld num2
    fcomi st,st(1)
    jnbe @F             ; Jump if ZF=0 & CF=0 - ST(0) > ST(1)
    fxch
    @@:
    fstp largest
    fstp st(0)              ; Just pop ST(0)

    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg3fmt, ADDR msg3, sum
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg4fmt, ADDR msg4, product
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg5fmt, ADDR msg5, largest

    xor eax, eax            ; Exitcode: 0
    ret
main endp
end
```